# Recover timestamps differences between PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, timezone, timestamp

As already said in the title, I've found a problem (and that's a very BIG problem) because of the PHP `date` function and the MySQL `NOW()` function.

This is the problem, in the MySQL table I've got a column named `aggiornamento` and an external ID column named `idesterno` which works like this:

- On insert, it gets inserted by MySQL's `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, and the
  `idesterno` gets inserted too
- On update, it checks for the `idesterno` and updates `aggiornamento` using PHP's `date` function

Here's the **BIG** problem (trust me, it' really a big problem):
MySQL `NOW()` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` returns correct time, `2016-09-04 13:20:00`, but PHP returns  correct too) another date, which is `2016-09-04 11:20:00`

So, when I insert the new record in the DB, all goes fine as I expect, but, when he gets updated, here comes the trouble.

I've found that the difference is in the timezone, MySQL has mine (`CEST`) and PHP doesn't, even if they're on the same server (yes, really funny), checked using `date_default_timezone_get`.

So, finally, what I need to know is this:
I know which one has been updated, but I don't know the exact time difference between the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `date('Y-m-d H:i:s)`.
I guess it's about 1 or 2 hours maximum (based on summer/winter time) but I can't edit this time without knowing if I'm doing it right

P.S. table entries are getting updated by a CRON which runs every 5 minutes

Comment: Have you tried to set date.timezone (http://php.net/manual/fr/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) in the php.ini ?

Comment: @vincenth I need to replace db `aggiornamento` column with correct timestamps, which are actually wrong because of the different timezone between MySQL and PHP. I've already set the PHP timezone, but, the problem is to correct older records, not the one which will saved now. Thank you by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,
hosting has set the "Europe/Rome" timezone into php.ini, but it gets overridden to UTC by Wordpress in misterious ways.

Anyway, after discovering this, I've force changed the default timezone in PHP scripts and updated the wrong db records adding 1 or 2 hours based on solar and legal time.